# Identity/Conditional Relations, Fitch Calculus in Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I have two fallacious arguments written propositionally:

If P, then Q 
If P, then R 
Therefore: If Q, then R

And

If P, then Q 
If R, then Q 
Therefore: If P, then R

However, if these particular propositions were interpreted as being connected not by a conditional sign but by an "=" (identity) sign, wouldn't we have examples of the transitive property (i.e. P=Q, P=R, so Q=R using the rule of identity elimination in Fitch calculus)? However, neither conditional/biconditional introduction/elimination in Fitch would be able to prove this -- hence it being a fallacy. The Fitch rules to which I'm referring are these:

https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~brianwc/courses/logic/rulesummary.html

Is what I'm implying by using "=" that P, Q, R are the exact same proposition?

Comment: Yes they would if it were, but it isn't so they needn't.

Comment: Because the identity symbol $=$ is not a propositipnal *connective* and thus the propositional Fitch rules (or others) do not "manage" it.

Answer (score 0):

If the statements did use an equality to connect the propositions, then the propositions would be equal.

That's obvious, but counterfactual.   The statements *do not* do so, so the propositions *need not* be equal.

While a *counterexample* will falsify an universal statement, a *single* example will not prove one.

---

**tl/dr** Look for a counterexample, rather than an example.